# Convert UTM coordinates from excel file to SHAPEFILE points in python?

Tags: pandas, arcgis, geopandas, google-earth

This image represents a list of components location in UTM coordinates in zone 17S.

However, I would like to visualize them in ArcGis Pro or Google Earth and must be a KMZ/KML or SHAPEFILE. Each coordinate should be displayed as a point, not a polygon

```
data = [['ROO01', 558635, 9303470],
        ['ROO02', 559203, 9303470]]
columns = ['ID', 'Easthing', 'Northing']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

[image]

How could I do that and obtain something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pyproj`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/).

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point

# https://epsg.io/32717
proj = pyproj.Proj('EPSG:32717')  # WGS 84 / UTM zone 17S
lon, lat = proj(df['Easthing'], df['Northing'], inverse=True)

df['geometry'] = list(map(Point, zip(lat, lon)))
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='WGS84')
gdf.to_file('layer.shp')
```

Output:

```
>>> gdf
      ID  Easthing  Northing                    geometry
0  ROO01    558635   9303470  POINT (-6.30120 -80.46989)
1  ROO02    559203   9303470  POINT (-6.30120 -80.46475)

>>> gdf.crs
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World.
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

>>> gdf.info()
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------    --------------  -----   
 0   ID        2 non-null      object  
 1   Easthing  2 non-null      int64   
 2   Northing  2 non-null      int64   
 3   geometry  2 non-null      geometry
dtypes: geometry(1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

Comment: I fixed my answer. I use `pyproj` rather than `utm` to convert coordinates. Can you check it please?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed!